# "Setting Up Personalized Settings for C:\ explorer.exe" message on boot

Tags: windows-7

I am constantly getting the message "Setting Up Personalized Settings for C:\ explorer.exe" at every boot.

I even tried to go to safe mode and delete the explorer.exe file from C drive, then the systems boots normally however, again the explorer.exe file comes up and the same issue.

Kindly suggest a permanent solution.

Comment: When you tried to delete it, did the file actually exist? Did it come back?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236436/en-us ("Setting Up Personalized Settings" Message at Every Boot
)

```
SYMPTOMS
You may receive the following message each time you start your computer:
Setting up Personalized settings
```

> CAUSE This behavior can occur if you have Internet Explorer installed
>   and the network is set up to use mandatory user profiles that are not
>   configured with Internet Explorer personalized settings.
>
> RESOLUTION 
>   WARNING: If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may
>   cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your
>   operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve
>   problems that result from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use
>   Registry Editor at your own risk.
>
> To work around this behavior, create a new mandatory user profile that
>   includes Internet Explorer personalized settings, or change the
>   BrowserWebCheck data value to a null value.
>
> For information about creating mandatory profiles, please see the
>   following article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 168476 How to
>   Create Mandatory Profiles with Windows NT 4.0 **To change the setting in
>   the registry, delete the Loadwc.exe value data from the
>   BrowserWebCheck value in the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run** For
>   additional information about Loadwc.exe, see the following article in
>   the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 176960 Description of the Loadwc.exe
>   File in Internet Explorer